# How to map a dynamic profile number to a servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

How could I map a dynamic profile number to a servlet for example

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585407
```

I want to map this 2585407 to a servlet is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913351/jsp-servlets-simple-question/2913396#2913396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and there are multiple options:

- use an [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to rewrite the given url to `questions?id=2585407`, then read the request parameter
- use some framework like Spring-MVC that supports beatiful URLs
- map the servlet to `/questions/*` (in web.xml) and then parse the `getRequestURI()` (by stripping the prefix and the `request.getContextPath()`)

Answer (score 1):

use following pattern in URL mapping

```
/questions/*
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `<url-mapping>` is set to

```
/questions/*
```

Then you would get your question id by using `request.getPathInfo()` (request being `HttpServletRequest`).